# Find the occurrence of specific Node in xml in XMLType column with xpath and having different namespace prefix for root and chaild node tag

Tags: oracle, xpath, namespaces

I have to find existence of specific node in XML which is present in an Oracle database column (`CLOB` datatype) in select query.

I thought of using the Oracle function `EXISTSNODE` to get expected result. The problem is that the namespaces of root and child node whose occurrence/existence has to be checked have different namespaces.

For example the XML looks like below :

```
<workcontract:workcontract 
     xmlns:workcontract ="http://schema.abc.nl/cdm/inc/v1" 
     xmlns:ns2="http://schema.abc.nl/cdm/ins/v1">
    <raamwerkcontract:verzekeringnemer>
        <workcontract:werkgever>
            <ns2:rekening>
                <ns2:rekeningnummer>123456789</ns2:rekeningnummer>
            </ns2:rekening>
        </workcontract:werkgever>
    </raamwerkcontract:verzekeringnemer>
</workcontract:workcontract>
```

I have to find if the XML contains the node at `/workcontract/verzekeringnemer/rekening`.

The signature of `EXISTSNODE` look like this:

```
EXISTSNODE(XMLType_instance, XPath_string, namespace_string)
```

`Namespace_string` argument is optional.

With multiple namespace_string’s how can I use the `EXISTSNODE` function?

My `SELECT` query works for node `werkgever` like this:

```
SELECT offerteId 
FROM QUOTATIONS 
WHERE EXISTSNODE(XMLTYPE(XMLOfferte), ’//workcontract:workcontract/raamwerkcontract:verzekeringnemer/ workcontract:werkgever’, ‘xmlns:workcontract ="http://schema.abc.nl/cdm/inc/v1"’) = 1;
```

Note : `XMLOfferte` column is of type `CLOB`.

How can I write query to find occurrence of node `rekening` which has different namespace i.e. `xmlns:ns2=”http://schema.abc.nl/cdm/ins/v1”`

Is there any other way than using the `EXISTSNODE` function?

Please help.

Regards,
Aniket

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? existsnode is deprecated from 11g anyway so you can use xmlexists instead?

Comment: Your XML sample uses a `raamwerkcontract` namespace prefix, which is not declared. Was this a copy/paste error?

Comment: @Alex Poole :  Oracle version is 12.1.0.1.0

Comment: @LarsH: Yes, it was copy/Paste mistake. It worked with XMLEXISTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear in the documentation, but you can supply multiple namespaces in the `existsnode()` namespace argument, optionally comma-separated; with `raamwerkcontract` added to your XML and the namespace argument (though you may just not have renamed that consistently while posting the question):

```
SELECT offerteId 
FROM QUOTATIONS 
WHERE EXISTSNODE(XMLTYPE(XMLOfferte),
  '//workcontract:workcontract/raamwerkcontract:verzekeringnemer/workcontract:werkgever',
  'xmlns:workcontract="http://schema.abc.nl/cdm/inc/v1" xmlns:raamwerkcontract="http://schema.abc.nl/cdm/inc/v1"') = 1;

 OFFERTEID
----------
        42
```

And with a third namespace for `ns2`:

```
SELECT offerteId 
FROM QUOTATIONS 
WHERE EXISTSNODE(XMLTYPE(XMLOfferte),
  '//workcontract:workcontract/raamwerkcontract:verzekeringnemer/workcontract:werkgever/ns2:rekening',
  'xmlns:workcontract="http://schema.abc.nl/cdm/inc/v1" xmlns:raamwerkcontract="http://schema.abc.nl/cdm/inc/v1" xmlns:ns2="http://schema.abc.nl/cdm/ins/v1"') = 1;

 OFFERTEID
----------
        42
```

You could also use wildcards, though that isn't ideal:

```
SELECT offerteId 
FROM QUOTATIONS 
WHERE EXISTSNODE(XMLTYPE(XMLOfferte),
  '//*:workcontract/*:verzekeringnemer/*:werkgever/*:rekening') = 1;

 OFFERTEID
----------
        42
```

However, [`existsnode()` is deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions057.htm), so you should be using [`xmlexists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions243.htm) instead anyway, and with that you can declare the namespaces as part of the XPath argument:

```
SELECT offerteId 
FROM QUOTATIONS 
WHERE XMLEXISTS('declare namespace workcontract="http://schema.abc.nl/cdm/inc/v1"; (: :)
  declare namespace raamwerkcontract="http://schema.abc.nl/cdm/inc/v1"; (: :)
  declare namespace ns2="http://schema.abc.nl/cdm/ins/v1"; (: :)
  /workcontract:workcontract/raamwerkcontract:verzekeringnemer/workcontract:werkgever/ns2:rekening'
  PASSING XMLTYPE(XMLOfferte)
);

 OFFERTEID
----------
        42
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. I had used wildcards for child node prefix like : //workcontract:workcontract/workcontract:verzekeringnemer/workcontract:werkgever/*:rekening. But then query performance was not good. XMLEXISTS works perfectly:)